# How can I run multiple threads inside of a given MPI process?

Tags: mpi, slurm

- I understand that a single MPI job Launches many processes which could be run on multiple nodes.
- How do I run multiple threads inside of a given MPI process using MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE?
- I was unable to find enough information in relation to the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your using OpenMP to run multiple threads 
You will write the OpenMP code as you would do with out the MPI. (this statement is over simplified)

When the MPI comes you need to consider how your process will communicate. MPI is not sending messages to individual threads but individual process. For that reason MPI provides four modes of interaction with threads.

1. `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`: Provides only one thread
2. `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`: Can provide many threads, but only the master thread can make MPI calls. The master thread is the one who call MPI_Init...
3. `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`: Can provide many threads, but only one can make MPI calls at a time.
4. `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPE`: Can provide many threads, and all of them can make MPI call at any time.

You need to specify the mode you want at MPI_Init, which becomes:
`MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, HERE_PUT_THE_MODE_YOU_NEED, PROVIDED_MODE)`
Ex:
    `MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPE, &provided)`

At the provided field the MPI_Init_thread returns the provided mode. Make sure that you got a mode that your code can cope with it.

Also, avoid the use of MPI_Probe and MPI_IProbe, because they are not thread save. You should use MPI_Mprobe and MPI_Improbe.

Here is a simple 'hello world' example as @ab2050 asked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int provided;
    int rank;

    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
    if (provided != MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning MPI did not provide MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED\n");
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    #pragma omp parallel default(none), \
                        shared(rank), \
                        shared(ompi_mpi_comm_world), \
                        shared(ompi_mpi_int), \
                        shared(ompi_mpi_char)
    {
        printf("Hello from thread %d at rank %d parallel region\n", 
                omp_get_thread_num(), rank);
        #pragma omp master
        {
            char helloWorld[12];
            if (rank == 0) {
                strcpy(helloWorld, "Hello World");
                MPI_Send(helloWorld, 12, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                printf("Rank %d send: %s\n", rank, helloWorld);
            }
            else {
                MPI_Recv(helloWorld, 12, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                         MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                printf("Rank %d received: %s\n", rank, helloWorld);
            }
        }

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

You have to run this code on two process. Because 'MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED' is selected only the master thread makes MPI calls.

The following variables are specified at OpenMP data scoping place 
because is needed by gcc version 6.1.1. Older versions like 4.8 do not require to declare them.

```
ompi_mpi_comm_world
ompi_mpi_char
```

Comment: Do you have sample code snippets that I could use to guide my development process?

Comment: Do you mean like a "hello world" program?